# Safely execute queries via AJAX on document ready

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, security

Greeting everybody,

My problem is like this: I have some custom made statistics on my internet site where I log informations on what users do ( google analytics - like ). Obviously I aggregate information a couple of months, but the Tables I store information have grown too large and have a negative impact on page loading. The flow is like this ( in index, so affect all pages ) :

```
1. Get the included files
2. Execute part of statistics queries
3. Effective page code
4. Execute the last part of statistics queries
```

To get rid of this problem I want to make those queries on `<body onload="execQueries();">` or on document ready with javascript / AJAX.

How can I safely and securely make those queries using AJAX, so that cannot be abused by a client with good knowledge of javascript/ajax. Because if I simply make that JS function it can be accesed everytime by a user with firebug.

The solution I think about is including the use of `$_SESSION` where I mark in top of my index.php information about those queries ( id, info ) and in the script called by AJAX I check if that `$_SESSION['query_info']` is set and I execute it reading all the info from there, and then I use `unset($_SESSION['query_info']);`. So, if the AJAX is called again, because tat specific `$_SESSION['query_info']` does not exists, I do not do anything in my DB.

Do you think this is a secure solution or do you have other ideas? Anything viable is welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: a user can abuse of your statistics even with your current implementation (browser refresh, curl script that hits the page several times a second). just do a classic get or post ajax request, it's the same as a page hit

Comment: @VladBalmos : not exactly because it does not alter the content of the query. It's like he abused google analytics, he does not abuse it, just makes consecutive request and I simply correctly log the requests.

Comment: well it all depends on your code and what kind of info you pass through the ajax request. doing a simple `$.get('/statistics/record_hit.php');` without any data it's the same as running your record hit query on the server side.

Comment: and one more thing. You can't really "secure" javascript in any way. there's nothing you can do really to make sure that the user doesn't modify your js code.

Comment: It is not just a record hit, it's far more complex. I do not have problems with queries as it is now. And if you had read my solution, I wanted to use `$_SESSION` as a validator value, not JS.

Comment: to be honest i will never put logs on database straight away... first wirte logs in in log file in certain format... and write script to process those log files... and run the script in cron ... obviously this method wont give you realtime stat but helps in security and performance..

Comment: @Surace this is an idea I did not think of. Thank you for the suggestion, I will consider it for sure

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your related javascript codes into [Closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).

Comment: Why would I do that? It does not offer security related advantages, or I don't understand what you mean. I can see all the JS code ( even if it is minified ), so I can backtrack everything.

Comment: basically, variables and functions wrapped in a closure can't be accessed using any developer tool (firebug or chrome dev. tool)

Comment: I have said in my question that I assume a user has knowledge of firebug, and I assume he has good knowledge, so I do not want to make JS validations.

Comment: you should 'uglify' it, as long as the request is made from JS anyone can execute it. I can copy the code and assign it to a function on run time and use it as many times as I want just to bother you.
Server side checks are better options

Comment: @DannYO : In my solution I wanted was to use $_SESSION to validate info inside the script called by AJAX. And if someone want to "abuse" it like that it is not a problem for me if all the queries are made using correct values. ( similar with a normal refresh/refresh/refresh. etc/ ).

Comment: "Safely execute queries via AJAX on document ready", that's the title of your question.